# How to check if disk has linux inside

Tags: linux, arch-linux, python

I am trying to boot a external USB drive which runs Linux to check whether the main computer hard drive is running (so it contains) Linux or not, and mount it into `/mnt` directory to modify some files.

I may be able to detect the devices (hard drives) plugged into the computer, but I have no idea how to detect if that disk has an OS in it and if that OS is any distort of Linux.

I'm trying to implement it in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three elements to the process of determining whether a disk "runs linux"

1. make a list of partitions to check
2. mount each partition
3. check each partition for some "magic" files
4. unmount each partition

For step 1, you can use 'parted' called via [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and parse the return value.

For step 2 and 4 use 'mount' resp. 'umount' via [subprocess.check_call()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call), as there is little need to parse the output.

That leaves step 3, where you can use `os.path.exists()` on the files you would like to change. If you don't want to update them, you can also just `open()` the files and catch the exception in case they don't exist (in which case you probably don't have a partition running Linux).

Be aware though that any subdirectories of the Linux directory tree can live on its own partition. Therefore checking for e.g. `/mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg` might not work on partition1 nor on partition2 because partition 2 is mounted under `/boot` on partition 1.

Comment: Simply trying to mount a partition directly is going to fail in cases where the partition is not a filesystem but for instance a Linux LVM physical volume or a member of Linux software RAID. A quick first level approach is indeed listing the partitions but then checking the file-system id's for typical Linux ones such as "82" - Linux swap or "83" - Linux filesystems such as EXT 1-4 or "8e" - Linux LVM etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you mount the partitions you should be able to check whether there is linux installed inside. To know which distribution, check the files `/etc/os-release`, `/etc/lsb-release`, `/etc/issue` and `/etc/issue.net`. You will find the name of the distribution in at least one of them.

Comment: Yeah, that would be easy if I did it manually, but I need to implement it into python... :) Maybe a shell script? Thanks.

Comment: @wonderwhy yeah, a shell script would work. Don't you think you should reword your question so that people can guess you want to do it from Python?